# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^4 -x^3+1}-\sqrt{x^4+15x^2-5}\,\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I wanna know how to do this limit

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\sqrt{x^4 -x^3+1}-\sqrt{x^4+15x^2-5}\,\right)$

Comment: Try multiplying and dividing by the conjugate root to eliminate the roots.

Comment: thats what i did, but i got stuck

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959619/find-c-and-p-such-that-sqrtx34x-sqrtx3x-sim-cxp-for-x-to-i/2959683#2959683

Comment: Remember that intuitively, when you work with limits of polynomials, you can often just replace the polynomial with it's leading term and get the right answer. In this case you get $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, rationalise the expression by multiplying numerator and denominator by$\displaystyle \sqrt{x^{4} -x^{3} +1} \ +\ \sqrt{x^{4} +15x^{2} -5}$
\begin{equation*}
\end{equation*}
We get
\begin{gather*}
\lim x\rightarrow \infty \ \frac{-x^{3} -15x^{2} +6}{\sqrt{x^{4} -x^{3} +1} \ +\ \sqrt{x^{4} +15x^{2} -5}}\\
\end{gather*}
Divide numerator and denominator by $\displaystyle x^{2}$
\begin{equation*}
\lim x\rightarrow \infty \ \frac{-x-15+\frac{6}{x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{x^{4}}} +\sqrt{1+\frac{15}{x^{2}} -\frac{5}{x^{4}}}}
\end{equation*}

Clearly the given expression tends to$\displaystyle \ -\infty $ as $\displaystyle x\rightarrow \infty $
\begin{equation*}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

You should multiply by the conjugate of the expression, then proceed.

\begin{align}
 \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^4 -x^3+1}-\sqrt{x^4+15x^2-5}\,\right)\left(\sqrt{x^4 -x^3+1}+\sqrt{x^4+15x^2-5}\,\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^4 -x^3+1}+\sqrt{x^4+15x^2-5}\,\right)}\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
 \frac{(x^4 -x^3+1)-(x^4+15x^2-5)}{\left(\sqrt{x^4 -x^3+1}+\sqrt{x^4+15x^2-5}\,\right)}
\end{align}

Operate and calculate the limit.

Comment: negative! that's cool!

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry I`m not a fully native english speaker so those two words in the same sentence make me confuse.

Comment: and then, should i evaluate de sign of de function to see the lateral limits?

Comment: No need if you just want to give a result of the limit. If you want to study the function then I suppose you should

Comment: Alberto, despues de eso tendria que evaluar el signo de f? ver si los limites laterales son iguales y obtener su valor?

Comment: ahh bien, creo que ya entiendo. gracias

Comment: After that you would fin that the limit can be $-\inf,\inf$, 0 or finite

Comment: rate the answer please

Answer (score -1):

Another manipulation:

Let $a,b >0$, real.

$a-b=(√a-√b)(√a+√b)$, then

$√a-√b = \dfrac{a-b}{√a+√b}.$

$a: = (x^4-x^3+1)^{1/2},$
$b=(x^4+15x^2-5)^{1/2}.$

$\small{f(x):=}$

$\small {=\dfrac{-x^3-15x^2+6}{(x^4-x^3+1)^{1/2}+(x^4+15x^2-5)^{1/2}}}$

Note : For large x (positive) the numerator is negative, the denominator positive: Increasing the denominator makes the fraction bigger.

Hence

$f(x) \lt $

$\dfrac{-x^3+6}{(x^4+1)^{1/2}+(x^4+15x^2)^{1/2}} \lt $

$\dfrac{-x^3+6}{√2x^2+√2x^2}=$

$\dfrac{-x^3+6}{(2√2)x^2}.$

Take the limit.